# bypass login of a webapp in order to connect like an user from help desk

Tags: java, security, authentication, active-directory, weblogic12c

I need to login a web application(internet) from another web application(intranet) deployed internal having only the username and without share the password.

I'd like to login like a customer from the internal help desk web site in order to give support in realtime and see the same things that the customer  see from home.

Is there away to use the security of the internal website based on active directory and Weblogic to login on the another web application accessible from internet and deployed on weblogic?

Answer (score 0):

"Oracle Co Browsing " helps you..[check here](https://www.oracle.com/applications/customer-experience/rightnow/contact-center-experience/cobrowse/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, but this is a cloud solution, I need to implement my own way I was thinking a token based solution.

Comment: As solution I have chosen SSO, in my case SAML as it is supported by Weblogic.